# How to Append to complex dictionary types in swift 3

Tags: swift, dictionary

How to append some empty array values to the below dictionary.

```
var results:Dictionary<String, Array<Dictionary<String, Any>> = [:]
```

`results["key"] = nil` doesn't work for me.

I want to have a dictionary like

```
{
"key1" : [],
"key2" : [],
"key3" : []
}
```

And should be possible to add `Dictionary<String, Any>` later in the place of `()`

Comment: Sorry, the notation `()` is not Swift. What is it supposed to mean?

Comment: just an empty array. capable of storing Dictionary<String, Any> type values

Comment: Empty array is `[]`.

Comment: No but I've answered the question! `results["key"] = []`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, your first line is illegal. It won't even compile. Please try always to show *real* code. So, your declaration might look like this:

```
var results : Dictionary<String, Array<Dictionary<String, Any>>> = [:]
```

Then to add an empty array to the dictionary, you would say:

```
results["key"] = []
```